# C# BackgroundWorker inside BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm facing an issue with BackgroundWorker in C#, hope you can help.
Here are some piece of code on my program

```
        var bwBIG = new BackgroundWorker();
        bwBIG.DoWork += (_senderBIG, argsBIG) =>
        {
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            String requestResult = "";
            bw.DoWork += (_sender, args) =>
            {
                requestResult = tempHelper.GetData();
            };
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (_sender, args) =>
            {
                makeData(requestResult);
            };
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }; //bwBIG.DoWork
        bwBIG.RunWorkerCompleted += (_senderBIG, argsBIG) =>
        {
            prepareData(rtbData.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Data OK");
        };
        bwBIG.RunWorkerAsync();
```

It suppose to run the tempHelper.GetData() , and then makeData(requestResult), and then finnally prepareData(rtbData.Text) then MessageBox.Show("Data OK");
However, it seems the bw is not running at all, whenever I run the code, it just jumped strange to MessageBox.Show("Data OK");
Any help please???
Thanks for reading.

Comment: At a glance your `bwBIG.Dowork` has nothing that will make it stop for any length of time. All you are doing is setting up another background worker and telling it to run async. You don't seem to be waiting for it `bw.DoWork` to finish so `bwBig` just finishes very quickly. And I've got to ask why do you set up a background task when all it does is creates a background task?

Comment: All your bwBIG does is set up and launch the inner BW. It exits immediately and fires RunWorkerCompleted. Not sure what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda useless to create backgroundworkerthread inside a worker thread.

I would keep it this way:

```
var localCopy = rtbData.Text;

var bwBIG = new BackgroundWorker();
bwBIG.DoWork += (_senderBIG, argsBIG) =>
{
    var requestResult = tempHelper.GetData();
    makeData(requestResult);

    prepareData(localCopy);

    MessageBox.Show("Data OK");
}; //bwBIG.DoWork
bwBIG.RunWorkerAsync();
```

It's kinda hard to see the flow of data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. However, the prepareData(rtbData.Text) must run AFTER the var requestResult = tempHelper.GetData(); done. tempHelper.GetData() is running for unknow period of time (2~30 seconds).